# Dynamic re-labeling of y-axis?

Tags: pgfplots

How can the y-axis in a plot like the one below be relabeled from 0-max (here 0-3) to 0-1 in a flexible way that is independent of the concrete data? Is it e.g. possible to access the maximal y-value that occurred during the plot and use it to determine the position of the y-label 1?

This question continues the discussion on [How do I plot a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of Discrete Numbers in LaTex Environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348520/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=3.5,
    xmin=14,xmax=35,
    xlabel={income},
    ylabel={cumulative distribution},
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    discontinuous,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
\addplot [red] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
P(x) f(x)
14   0
15  1/5
18  2/5
25 3/5
31 4/5
33 1
35 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are referring to **tick**-labels here right? And you want to normalize them by the maximum y-value of the data?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, tick-labels, this is how I understand the OP of the original question in the other thread. And the topmost label corresponding to the maximal value of the plot should be 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pgfplots: read data, calculate diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185488/pgfplots-read-data-calculate-diagram) you can calculate the cumulative percentage, add it as extra column, and plot that column.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

\pgfplotstableread{
P(x)    f(x)
14  0
15  1/5
18  2/5
25  3/5
31  4/5
33  1
35  0
}\datatable
% Calculate the sum of the y column
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplotstablesum{0}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{f(x)}\of\datatable\as\yvalue{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplotstablesum{\pgfplotstablesum+\yvalue}
}
% Define a "virtual column" that calculates the cumulative percentage on the fly
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/cumulative percentage/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}/\pgfplotstablesum}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.0,
    xmin=14,xmax=35,
    xlabel={income},
    ylabel={cumulative distribution},
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    discontinuous
]
\addplot [red] table [y=cumulative percentage]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]