# Modifying axis step values without changing the data in Pgfplots

Tags: tables, pgfplots, plot

I want to draw a chart using a table using Pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.txt}
x   y
0.01042 -4.98E-04
0.02084 -2.006E-03
0.03126 -4.487E-03
0.04167 -7.852E-03
0.05209 -1.179E-02
0.0625  -1.476E-02
0.07292 -1.56E-02
0.08334 -1.573E-02
0.09376 -1.581E-02
0.10417 -1.586E-02
0.11459 -1.592E-02
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=-0.02, ymax =0.0,
xmin=0.0, xmax =0.1, 
]    
\addplot[] table {data1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, the output looks like this.

[image]

However, I want to multiply y axis step values by 100 without modifying the data itself, and want something like this.

[image]

Is there any way to do this? To clarify the context, in my original data, y is in metre, but the values are so small that I want to change it to centimetre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use the `pgfplotstable` package and add a virtual column to your table that contains the value from the *y* column multiplied by 100 (inspiration taken from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186016/47927)):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.txt}
x       y
0.01042 -4.98E-04
0.02084 -2.006E-03
0.03126 -4.487E-03
0.04167 -7.852E-03
0.05209 -1.179E-02
0.0625  -1.476E-02
0.07292 -1.56E-02
0.08334 -1.573E-02
0.09376 -1.581E-02
0.10417 -1.586E-02
0.11459 -1.592E-02
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{data1.txt}\datatable
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/multiplied y value/.style={
        create col/expr={100*\thisrow{y}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=-2, ymax=0,
xmin=0.0, xmax=0.1, 
]    
\addplot[] table [y=multiplied y value] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That sorted my problem perfectly.